# Using Tags or Metadata for images on both PC and Mac

Tags: tags, filesystems, cross-platform, metadata

I'm looking to build out a searchable image library for my company.  We have thousands of images and I'm trying to find the best way to "tag them" so-to-speak.  The images are stored on a network drive and accessed by both Mac and Windows users.  I work on a Mac and have Adobe Bridge, but not everyone accessing these images will.  I've seen that in Windows, you can add tags to files for searching, and in OS X, you can add Spotlight comments (delimited by commas, it can be used as search tags), however, the 2 don't carry over across platforms.

Is there anything out there that may help in accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 3):

For storing metadata with images, there is the **IPTC** standard. This standard allows you to save information in predefined fields such as Headline, Abstract or Keywords. Any file format that is compatible with this standard can embed the data within the file. Think of IPTC as an extended Exif standard.

The IPTC standard itself has been improved by Adobe and called **XMP** (abbr. for *Extensible Metadata Platform*). XMP is part of an ISO standard and can be embedded in most image files nowadays, including TIFF, JPG, PNG, GIF, PDF and a lot of RAW image files. And if you're dealing with files that don't support XMP embedding, you can use this standard via sidecar files (external .xmp files containing all the XMP information). There are several libraries for XMP. The "official" [Adobe XMP SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) provides a C++ library, several other XMP libraries are [listed here](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/XMP_Implementations).

The big advantage of using XMP is that the information will be compatible with any other modern image management software you'll be using. Even if your solution should become obsolete one day, Adobe Bridge (or Acdsee or XnView and so on) can access the data that has been entered. And you're not even restricted to Windows and Mac; there are XMP-based solutions for Linux as well.

Of course your image library should come along with a simple database that will allow for fast searches. For a similar solution I've used an SQLite database stored along with the images on the file server and that is updated every time an image is added or edited. This database just mirrors the information from the XMP fields and can easily be rebuilt at any time from the image files itself.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended XMP key to store simple keywords is dc:subject according to Metadata Working Group guidelines.

http://www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf

They also have a schema for hierarchical keywords, but nobody uses that. The defacto standard for those is lr:hierarchicalSubject

To confirm that your applications write to this XMP keys you can use the commandline exiftool or exiv2. Both of these tools are multi-platform: Windows, OS X, Linux, etc.

If you need a cross platform DAM, try digikam. Using the same app on all your platforms eliminates compatibility issues.